# How to mock customized logger with static keyword using Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, static, mocking, mockito, static-methods

I have created customized logging library named "StandardLogger" in which I am using logback for logging. Now I want to mock it in unit test but I am unable to do it.

- Function I want to mock is static

```
   public static String getHostOrDefault(String url, String defaultHost) {
       try {
           return new URL(url).getHost();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           logger.error("ConfigurationProvider", "getHostOrDefault", "Exception returning default host : "+ defaultHost + " Exception : "+e);
       }
       return defaultHost;
   }
```

- Class name and field

```
@Context
public class ConfigurationProvider {

    private static final StandardLogger logger = new StandardLogger("CATS");
```

- My Test class with unit test

```
class ConfigurationProviderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ConfigurationProvider configurationProvider;

    @Mock
    private StandardLogger logger= new StandardLogger("CATS");

    @Test
    void  thatGetHostOrDefaultReturnsHost() {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(logger).info(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString());
        String hostOrDefault = ConfigurationProvider.getHostOrDefault("http://abc.host:9433", "host");
        assertThat(hostOrDefault, is("abc.host"));
    }
```

Now when I am running it in debug mode logger object is NULL .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the class under test you aren't injecting the logger. This means that you cannot inject it from the junit either. And exactly this happens: your logger is null in your class under test!

The second problem faces to you is about static methods. I've never been able to mock static method without using [PowerMockito](https://powermock.github.io/), even if [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods) there is an  interesting article that says that you can do it.

Comment: I have already tried annotations InjectMocks , Spy also but didn't get any result. Second I have already followed your mentioned article it have different examples not related to mine but it also didn't work for me. In last I only have PowerMockito I should try this now.